# Find the acute angles of this right triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

I am having trouble finding the acute angles of this triangle. O is the intersection of the medians of the triangle and $OG = \frac{1}{2}OH$. Any suggestions?

Comment: $O$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$?  As in $OA = OB = OC$?

Comment: Is that what it means? I swear my textbook says that the circumcenter is the intersection of the medians. Will fix it right away.

Comment: Intersection of the medians is a centroid.

Comment: They must have made a typo...

Comment: So which one is it??

Comment: Well, I said I would edit it so it is what it says in the question - centroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being $O$ the centroid of the right $\triangle ABC$ we have that $\triangle ABO$, $\triangle BCO$ and $\triangle CAO$ have the same area, then
\begin{align*}
\mbox{Area }BCO&=\mbox{Area }ABO\\
\frac{1}{2}|BC|\times |OH|&=\frac{1}{2}|AB|\times|OG|\\
\implies\frac{|BC|}{|AB|}&=\frac{|OG|}{|OH|}\\
\cos\measuredangle ABC&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore $\measuredangle ABC=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\measuredangle CAB=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but this problem is posed in a textbook not involving trigonometry so I am looking for a different approach.+1

Comment: On the other hand, thanks to your idea of using the areas I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to note the points H and G are in the circle of diameter OB. Then calculate sin and cos of angle CBO and ABO. With this you have angle CBA and BAC is the complementaire.